# Cocoa - detect event when camera started recording

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video-capture

In my OSX application I'm using code below to show preview from camera.

```
  [[self session] beginConfiguration];

  NSError *error = nil;
  AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

  if (captureDevice != nil) {
    [[self session] removeInput: [self videoDeviceInput]];
    if([[self session] canAddInput: newVideoDeviceInput]) {
      [[self session] addInput:newVideoDeviceInput];
      [self setVideoDeviceInput:newVideoDeviceInput];
    } else {
      DLog(@"WTF?");
    }
  }

  [[self session] commitConfiguration];
```

Yet, I need to detect the exact time when the preview from the camera becomes available.

In other words I'm trying to detect the same moment like in Facetime under OSX, where animation starts once the camera provides the preview.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (Just out of curiosity).

Comment: I would like to invoke some effects in similar fashion like in case of FT.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is really old, but I stumbled upon it too when I was looking for this same question, and I have found answers so here goes.

For starters, AVFoundation is too high level, you'll need to drop down to a lower level, CoreMediaIO. There's not a lot of documentation on this, but basically you need to perform a couple queries.

To do this, we'll use a combination of calls. First, `CMIOObjectGetPropertyDataSize` lets us get the size of the data we'll query for next, which we can then use when we call `CMIOObjectGetPropertyData`. To set up the get property data size call, we need to start at the top, using this property address:

```
var opa = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyDevices),
    mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
    mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster)
)
```

Next, we'll set up some variables to keep the data we'll need:

```
var (dataSize, dataUsed) = (UInt32(0), UInt32(0))
var result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyDataSize(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &opa, 0, nil, &dataSize)
var devices: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil
```

From this point on, we'll need to wait until we get some data out, so let's busy loop:

```
repeat {
    if devices != nil {
        free(devices)
        devices = nil
    }
    devices = malloc(Int(dataSize))
    result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &opa, 0, nil, dataSize, &dataUsed, devices);
} while result == OSStatus(kCMIOHardwareBadPropertySizeError)
```

Once we get past this point in our execution, `devices` will point to potentially many devices. We need to loop through them, somewhat like this:

```
if let devices = devices {
    for offset in stride(from: 0, to: dataSize, by: MemoryLayout<CMIOObjectID>.size) {
        let current = devices.advanced(by: Int(offset)).assumingMemoryBound(to: CMIOObjectID.self)
        // current.pointee is your object ID you will want to keep track of somehow
    }
}
```

Finally, clean up `devices`

```
free(devices)
```

Now at this point, you'll want to use that object ID you saved above to make another query. We need a new property address:

```
var CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIODevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere),
    mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeWildcard),
    mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementWildcard)
)
```

This tells CoreMediaIO that we want to know if the device is currently running somewhere (read: in any app), wildcarding the rest of the fields. Next we get to the meat of the query, `camera` below corresponds to the ID you saved before:

```
var (dataSize, dataUsed) = (UInt32(0), UInt32(0))
var result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyDataSize(camera, &opa, 0, nil, &dataSize)
if result == OSStatus(kCMIOHardwareNoError) {
    if let data = malloc(Int(dataSize)) {
        result = CMIOObjectGetPropertyData(camera, &opa, 0, nil, dataSize, &dataUsed, data)
        let on = data.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        // on.pointee != 0 means that it's in use somewhere, 0 means not in use anywhere
    }
}
```

With the above code samples you should have enough to test whether or not the camera is in use. You only need to get the device once (the first part of the answer); the check for if it's in use however, you'll have to do at any time you want this information. As an extra exercise, consider playing with `CMIOObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock` to be notified on event changes for the in use property address we used above.

While this answer is nearly 3 years too late for the OP, I hope it helps someone in the future. Examples here are given with Swift 3.0.

Comment: Thank you your example worked fine. Can this be used to detect audio mic usage too?

Comment: This method cannot be directly used to detect microphone use, but detecting microphone use is actually not as difficult as camera. You can use AMCoreAudio for most of the heavy lifting. The way I did it was listen for the nameDidChange and isRunningSomewhereDidChange to update internal state, and to detect when the microphone is in use somewhere. I hope that's enough information to get you started, comments are only so long.

Comment: Appreciate the response. What do u think of calling subprocess in a 5 second timer - ""ioreg -c AppleHDAEngineInput | grep IOAudioEngineState" . Would using AMCoreAudio perform better?  I will explore AMCoreAudio thanks

Comment: In my opinion, using AMCoreAudio is better because it's reactive to the system events, versus repeatedly invoking an external process which itself is fragile.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow adopt this for virtual cameras / DAL devices? I have already enabled them using kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices and I can list them, however IsRunningSomewhere doesn't seem to apply to them.

Comment: I am not totally sure Tobias, I haven't tried this ever. My gut feeling is that what you describe should work, but given this isn't the best documented framework in the apple ecosystem, finding that exact answer might be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, it works... but one time, somehow it is not able to detect the change of state of the camera, it continues to report the same result (all variables have been reset or reallocated), only way is to restart the app. Still no meaningful docs or have someone found them?

Comment: @rustyDev Sounds like you have not properly added this to the run loop. The behaviour you describe happens when it's not in the run loop anyway, though there may be other causes. I would strongly urge you to focus there as you debug the problem.

Comment: @TobiasTimpe I found a solution for virtual devices: https://github.com/wouterdebie/onair/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer from the user [jer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172881/jer) is definitely the correct answer, but I just wanted to add one additional important information.

If a listener block is registered with `CMIOObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock`, the current run loop must be run, otherwise no event will be received and the listener block will never fire.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, and why I listed it as an "extra exercise" :) Learning these kinds of things has wide-ranging implications; my gentle nudge into learning more about the platform. :)