# How can I tell if the camera is in use by another process?

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation

In OS X, how can I tell if the camera or microphone is in use by another application or process? The following doesn't seem to work unless the other application has locked the device.

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    NSLog(@"In use by other application %hhd", [device isInUseByAnotherApplication]);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CoreAudio to check if microphone is in use or not.

`AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };`

```
UInt32 dataSize = 0;
OSStatus status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize);
if(kAudioHardwareNoError != status) {
    fprintf(stderr, "AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize (kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices) failed: %i\n", status);
    //return NULL;
    return;
}

UInt32 deviceCount = (UInt32)(dataSize / sizeof(AudioDeviceID));

AudioDeviceID *audioDevices = (AudioDeviceID*)(malloc(dataSize));
if(NULL == audioDevices) {
    fputs("Unable to allocate memory", stderr);
    return;
}

status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, audioDevices);
if(kAudioHardwareNoError != status) {
    fprintf(stderr, "AudioObjectGetPropertyData (kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices) failed: %i\n", status);
    free(audioDevices), audioDevices = NULL;
    return ;
}

CFMutableArrayRef inputDeviceArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, deviceCount, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
if(NULL == inputDeviceArray) {
    fputs("CFArrayCreateMutable failed", stderr);
    free(audioDevices), audioDevices = NULL;
    return ;
}`
```

Now Iterate through all the devices and fetch property data `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere`

`CFBooleanRef deviceIsRunning = NULL;
        dataSize = sizeof(deviceIsRunning);
        propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere;
        status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(audioDevices[i], &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &deviceIsRunning);`

Check deviceIsRunning variable.

I don't have idea about video device. But i will update my answer if i find some solution.

Hope this help.

Comment: I answer the video part in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973669/cocoa-detect-event-when-camera-started-recording/41519165#41519165

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on go module that detects camera/microphone state (using `cgo`) and here is my Objective-C implementations:

- `IsCameraOn()`: https://github.com/antonfisher/go-media-devices-state/blob/main/pkg/camera/camera_darwin.mm
- `IsMicrophoneOn()`: https://github.com/antonfisher/go-media-devices-state/blob/main/pkg/microphone/microphone_darwin.mm

Thanks @Rohan for the accepted answer!

Comment: Does it also detect for external microphone? like airpods microphone