# How can I determine if a WebCam is being used in macOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to create a simple application that lets me know when any cameras on my Mac (built-in or otherwise) are being used.

I've yet to find any methods that tell me this and the following code (running in an Xcode 11 Playground using Swift 5.2) always return the same values whether my external camera is being used by Zoom or not:

```swift
import AVFoundation

let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .externalUnknown], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

for device in discoverySession.devices {
    print(device.localizedName)

    let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
    let available: String = captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) ? "true": "false"

    print("\tConnected: \(device.isConnected)")
    print("\tSuspended: \(device.isSuspended)")
    print("\tAvailable: \(available)")
    print("\tIs In Use: \(device.isInUseByAnotherApplication)")
    print()
}
```

And here is the output I get regardless of whether an application is using the camera or not:

```
FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
    Connected: true
    Suspended: true
    Available: true
    Is In Use: false

C922 Pro Stream Webcam #4
    Connected: true
    Suspended: false
    Available: true
    Is In Use: false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if the camera is in use by another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470201/how-can-i-tell-if-the-camera-is-in-use-by-another-process)

Comment: @willeke The accepted answer for that question is only about audio and specifically states, "I don't have idea about video device. But i will update my answer if i find some solution."

Comment: Read the comment please.